Where should the Cff cap be placed in this design?
I used the power design tool from TI for the LMR51430XF buck converter (the details are in the first screenshot). In the design, I have a Cff CAP that doesn't appear anywhere in the datasheet of the component. I am curious why is the cap there and also where should I place it when I am doing the layout of the switch(see second screenshot).





It's a feedforward capacitor which improves stability and bandwidth. It can be used to optimize the feedback transient response to make the regulator to respond faster to changing load.
Since it is in parallel with the top feedback resistor, it will go right next to that resistor on PCB so it has very short tracks to that resitor, no matter where you place them.
And if your next question is which way C25 and R5 should be on your PCB, it does not matter a least bit.

I've added 2 screenshots to the post. Are both placements of the C25(Cff) pin alright(R5 = Rfbt, R6 = Rfbb) ? Thank you for the help!
